# There was a way to flag questions as 'difficult to be generalized'

Tags: support, moderation, flagging

This applies to a few questions out there, especially the ones asking for personal career advice.

Was this function removed during graduation of the site? Or is it just me who can't access it anymore?

**Edit** My guess is that when the site graduated I lost the moderation privilege due to my low reputation. This option used to show up immediately upon hitting the 'close' link, and now I don't see it anymore but buried 4 layers down the flagging dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Difficult to generalize" is now found under the Flag option by selecting "another reason," then "off-topic." It's a bit buried, but now you have more options to choose from.

Comment: Great, more options is good. I was actually referring to questions that are too specific, rather than too generalized, but your answer point out the right thing.

Comment: @aeismail "Too generalized" is not what my problem is, at least. There's a lot of questions here that are *very* specific to someone's situation, and unlikely to be helpful to anyone but the OP. It would be nice to have a means of flagging those.

Comment: @Fomite I think it's just a typo. The option can be found in: Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic 'Questions that cannot be generalized to apply to others in similar situations are off-topic. For assistance […] see: What kinds of questions are too localized?'

Comment: @Jigg I think my problem is I see Flagging and voting to Close to be separate processes. It is indeed in the Close options.

Comment: Yeah, I got the title wrong. It should have said "too specialized" or "difficult to be generalized."

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that option either - the closest thing I can see to it is just "It needs moderator attention".

It would be nice to have either a close vote or flagging option for that. I personally find "this is too hard to render into a non-single use question" much more common than "Too Broad" as a reason I want to see things closed or edited.

Comment: While @aeismail's approach is better, this is definitely acceptable as well.